# Mysql query not working on server but working fine locally

Tags: php, mysql

My query to log into the system runs fine locally, but when uploaded on the server. It does not return anything in PHP.  Here is the query:

```
"SELECT `UserID` 
   FROM `" . DB_NAME . "`.`Login` 
  WHERE `UserName` = '" . $UserName . "' 
    AND `UserPassword` = '" . $Password . "';"
```

...and here is my PHP code:

```
$UserName = $_POST['txtUserName'];
$Password = md5($_POST['txtPassword']);

$qry = "SELECT `UserID` 
          FROM `" . DB_NAME . "`.`Login` 
         WHERE `UserName` = '" . $UserName . "' 
           AND `UserPassword` = '" . $Password . "';";

$result = mysql_query($qry);

session_start();

if ($result) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $User = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['UserID'] = $User['UserID'];
        session_write_close();
        mysql_close();
        exit();
    } else {
        //Login failed
        mysql_close();
        die('Invalid UserName and Password combination...');
    }
} else {
    mysql_close();
    die('Query failed...' . mysql_error());
}
```

The output returned is:

`Query failed...`

Comment: Anddddd... what was the error?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php Also, you are wide open to SQL injection.  Look into PDO with parameterized queries or something.

Comment: `echo $qry` after the db, username & password have been set in the string.

Comment: where to see the details of error on `PHPMyAdmin`

Comment: You sure you connect fine to the sql database? Are you using different username and password on the server than from the localhost? Also, +1 to Brad for suggesting PDO.

Comment: yes. i have successfully connected to the server. Because the error is `Query failed...`, which is the last line of the code file...

Comment: @Naveed Butt doesn't mean that it's connecting to the database though. It could be that the query is wrong. Do what ponies said. Echo $qry and make sure it's correct. Also take out mysql_close or put it after die() and see if there is an error. If so what is the error if it's printed to the page. You can also do var_dump($result) to see if it returned anything. should be something like resource(1)

Comment: Thanks to Brad for his link. I managed to find out the error, which stated `could not find the table`. It was because of case insensitive table name... Why did the query run on my machine locally but not on server...

Comment: are you using windows on your machine and linux on the server? If so then this would probably be why.

Comment: yes my OS is windows, but no idea about the OS of Server...

Comment: In addition to @Brad comment about SQL injection, if the rest of your site is constructed in this manner of building sql string from web-submitted values, every one of your OTHER queries is ALSO subject to SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`As no one has responded in the answers area. I want to reply the post myself for future clarification of anyone arriving here and seeing this post.`

The issue was with the name of the table. I spelled it `Login`, whereas, the original table name was `login`.

I don't know why this thing showed up on server only. i.e., it was working fine locally on my machine, but the issue arrived on server only.

I fixed the issue by renaming the table name in the query.

HTH, Thank you,

Comment: If you local machine is windows and live system is linux issue can be lower case and upper case as linux doesn't treat both as same but windows does